# error al conectarme a MSSQL 2008 sin instancia

Tags: sql, nodejs, npm

Tengo 2 conexiones con `node` usando el paquete `mssql`

```
var config = {

    user: 'xx',
    password: 'xx',
    server: 'DESARROLLO\\PROGRAMACION',
    database: 'prueba',
    options: {
       encrypt: true
     }

}
```

Esta funciona porque tiene instancia y tengo otra:

```
var config = {

    user: 'xx',
    password: 'xx',
    server: 'DESARROLLO', 
    database: 'pruebabase2',
    options: {
       encrypt: true
     }
}
```

Esta no tiene instancia y es un motor `sql 2008` igual que la otra pero la que no tiene instancia no conecta.

Las 2 conexiones usan esto:

```
sql.connect(config, function(err) {

    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select 1 as number', function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks 
        console.log(err); 
        console.dir(recordset);
    });
});
```

Con la primera conexión sale bien pero con la segunda conexión sale mal los 2 sevidores tiene el mismo sistema operativo y los mismo motores

¿Alguien sabe que debo configurar en el servidor para que la que no tiene instancia conecte? ya que devuelve el siguiente error:

Estoy seguro que debe ser alguna configuración en el servidor que no maneja instancia

> { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
>       at ConnectionError (D:\Proyectos\Mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1428:7)
>       at Request._query (D:\Proyectos\Mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1300:37)
>       at Request._query (D:\Proyectos\Mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:497:11)
>       at Request.query (D:\Proyectos\Mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1243:12)
>       at D:\Proyectos\Mssql\app.js:62:13
>       at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (D:\Proyectos\Mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:270:7) code:
>   'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecute lo siguiente en tu SQL 2008 y usa el resultado como el valor para el key 'server' en config:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME + '\' + @@SERVICENAME AS nombreInstancia
```